# encrypted password doesn't work in activemq

Tags: encryption, activemq-classic

I'm trying to encrypt passwords used for establishing and connecting to activemq queue. I'm following up the steps [HERE](http://activemq.apache.org/encrypted-passwords.html) and I'm able to start activemq with the new activemq-security.xml file. I have a script that trys to create and connect to the queue but I keep getting errors that username or password is invalid.

I encrypted the password for consumer user and stored the encrypted password in credentials-enc.properties file like:

```
consumer.password=ENC(awknernfjewnwk)
```

I tried different things and I'm sure that the credentials-enc.properties is not getting picked up for some reason, here is how its defined:

```
        <beans
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

        <bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
          <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
          <property name="passwordEnvName" value="ACTIVEMQ_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
          <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
          <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
          <property name="location" value="file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials-enc.properties"/>
        </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" advisorySupport="false" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
        <plugins>
             <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
                    <users>
                        <authenticationUser username="admin" password="admin"
                            groups="admins"/>
                        <authenticationUser username="consumer" password="$(consumer.password)"
                            groups="readers"/>
                        <authenticationUser username="producer" password="$(producer.password)"
                            groups="writers"/>
                    </users>
                </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
              <authorizationPlugin>
               <map>
                <authorizationMap>
                   <authorizationEntries>
                     <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="readers" write="admins" admin="admins" />
                     <authorizationEntry queue="CLIMATE" read="readers" write="writers" admin="admins" />
                     <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins,readers" write="admins,writers" admin="admins" />
                   </authorizationEntries>
                   <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
                     <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/>
                   </tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
                </authorizationMap>
              </map>
           </authorizationPlugin>
          </plugins>
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
```

Below is an image of the error log I'm getting:
[image]

config for transport connector

```
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Any ideas what might be the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple in fact, you use for variables **$(producer.password)** but it's wrong, you need **${producer.password}** !!

that's all.

Note that the queue "CLIMATE" must be created because user "consumer" is not in admins group and cannot create it.

Comment: thanks Hassen for your reply! yes, I used `ACTIVEMQ_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=activemq` I have also tried providing `activemq` as a property in configuration file. The consumer encryption I provided is just a sample not the actual result I got after encrypting it, I'm pretty sure the location property specifying credentials-enc.properties is not getting picked up as I tried using it without encryption and it failed again. `Stopping tcp://XXXX because Failed with SecurityException: User name [consumer] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ BrokerServic`

Comment: you can rename credentials-enc.properties to test if on the broker startup you will have a FileNotFoundException

Comment: Hassen, I tried renaming the credentials file and as you expected I had a file not found exception. I'm using the latest AMQ release 5.14.1 also I attached a copy of my log to my question above. (removed some data related to my system and highlighted tcp connection AMQ trying to connect to, I'm wondering why it has `:34635@61617` I'm using port 61617 not default 61616 btw?

Comment: it seems that tcp is configured to use 61617 , what did you mean by **tcp connection AMQ trying to connect to** ? did you have a network of brokers ? can you post transportConnectors configs, in your startup logs you can verify tcp port started with some thing like this ** INFO  | Connector tcp://localhost:61616 started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector **

Comment: Hi Hassan, I configured tcp to use 61617 and I don't have a network of brokers. I meant by my question is the highlighted lines from the log image above shows the tcp connection which is correct but there is `34635` for example before `@61617` I'm wondering what is this number represents (the 34635)? added transport connector config above

Comment: 34635 is the port opened on consumer host. I think that your consumer still running and retry to reconnect, is it right ? Can you please post your consumer code and logs. Change AMQ log level to trace or use this plugin and add parameters to log all events http://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Hassen!!!!! I can't believe how I missed that! you were so patient and helpful with me thanks a lot!